# Apache 2.2 rewrite - Force all requests to index.html

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, rewrite

I need to force all requests regardless of what they are to index.html. Unfortunately everything I have tried has not worked properly.

The following seems to me like it should work but it doesn't. My understanding is that it is saying for anything that doesn't end in /index.html to actually request the index.html file.

Redirect 302 !^/index.html http://www.example.com/index.html

Any help/clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using an .htaccess on the root folder this should do the job:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteRule . /index.html [R=302,L]
```

The condition and rule is that if the request does not match index.html it will redirect whatever to it

Comment: Would you happen to know if it is possible to do this for all IPs except specified ones?

Comment: You mean ip from those accessing the website or ips within the server ? update your question with an example of what you are looking for and i will check it out.

Comment: Is there any way to make this work just for requests made on a subfolder of the root dir? SO that requesting www.site.com/folder/foo.php triggers the redirect while www.site.com/foo.php doesn't.

Comment: Don't forget to set `AllowOverride All` in the `Directory` directive for the `.htaccess` to be taken into account.

Answer (score 9):

Answer of @prix is good. I myself needed to add conditions so that normal resources (images & css) are served as normal:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|svg|woff|ttf|eot)$
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

Comment: use 'RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html' instead of porn like 'RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt|svg|woff|ttf|eot)$'

Answer (score 4):

I voted up the other answers, but in the end they didn't quite help me because I included a logo in the index.html file. So here are my adjustments. First of all, the prerequisites.

Change

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride All
```

in

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
…
<Directory /var/www/>
```

to enable .htaccess file in `/var/www/html` (example).

---

Create or edit file

```
/var/www/html/.htaccess
```

with content

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.+/logo\.png$
RewriteRule . /logo.png [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/logo\.png$
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

As you can see, I'm not using a redirect. This means that the path or URI entered by the user remains the same; nevertheless, the index.html page is displayed with the logo.

Comment: Worked for our react projects, thanks a ton.